# no. of nodes keep fluctuating in selenium grid

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, docker-swarm, selenium-grid

I am using docker swarm based selenium grid, the same docker compose used to work on azure based VM's but on GCP is giving issue. All the nodes come up when I deploy the grid but as tests start running the number of nodes keep reducing and tests fail.

```
01:17:29.140 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - Unable to execute request for an existing session: Unable to find session with ID: 438df7f8fbf108115a19cdee31d96494
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: '8fb32b33e907', ip: '10.0.1.8', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN48Z.png)os.version: '5.15.0-1031-gcp', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
01:17:29.140 WARN [SeleniumSpanExporter$1.lambda$export$1] - org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Unable to find session with ID: 438df7f8fbf108115a19cdee31d96494
Build info: version: '4.2.2', revision: '683ccb65d6'
System info: host: '8fb32b33e907', ip: '10.0.1.8', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-1031-gcp', java.version: '11.0.15'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.sessionmap.local.LocalSessionMap.get(LocalSessionMap.java:129)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.HandleSession.lambda$loadSessionId$4(HandleSession.java:159)
        at io.opentelemetry.context.Context.lambda$wrap$2(Context.java:224)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.HandleSession.execute(HandleSession.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$PredicatedRoute.handle(Route.java:373)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.router.Router.execute(Router.java:91)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.web.EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.lambda$apply$0(EnsureSpecCompliantResponseHeaders.java:34)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route$CombinedRoute.handle(Route.java:336)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Route.execute(Route.java:68)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.lambda$apply$0(AddWebDriverSpecHeaders.java:35)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorFilter.lambda$apply$0(ErrorFilter.java:44)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter$1.execute(Filter.java:64)
        at org.openqa.selenium.netty.server.SeleniumHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(SeleniumHandler.java:44)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

I tried updating docker image, fixing DNS resolution and restarting the grid, but with every restart the nodes come up once and then start reducing with time.

I am using docker compose file similar to this " https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/blob/trunk/docker-compose-v3-swarm.yml "
And the following command to scale the nodes: docker service scale -c docker_compose sel

docker logs give the following exception:

```html
java.net.UnknownHostException: selenium-hub: Name or service not known
        at java.base/java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1519)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress$NameServiceAddresses.get(InetAddress.java:848)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1509)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1368)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1302)
        at java.base/java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1252)
        at org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.UnboundZmqEventBus.isSubAddressIPv6(UnboundZmqEventBus.java:170)
        at org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.UnboundZmqEventBus.lambda$new$6(UnboundZmqEventBus.java:125)
        at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$toCtxSupplier$9(Functions.java:228)
        at dev.failsafe.Functions.lambda$get$0(Functions.java:46)
        at dev.failsafe.internal.RetryPolicyExecutor.lambda$apply$0(RetryPolicyExecutor.java:74)
        at dev.failsafe.SyncExecutionImpl.executeSync(SyncExecutionImpl.java:193)
        at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.call(FailsafeExecutor.java:376)
        at dev.failsafe.FailsafeExecutor.run(FailsafeExecutor.java:220)
        at org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.UnboundZmqEventBus.<init>(UnboundZmqEventBus.java:122)
        at org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.ZeroMqEventBus.create(ZeroMqEventBus.java:53)
        at org.openqa.selenium.events.zeromq.ZeroMqEventBus.create(ZeroMqEventBus.java:79)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.ClassCreation.callCreateMethod(ClassCreation.java:50)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.lambda$getClass$4(MemoizedConfig.java:100)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1705)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.config.MemoizedConfig.getClass(MemoizedConfig.java:95)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.EventBusOptions.createBus(EventBusOptions.java:51)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.server.EventBusOptions.getEventBus(EventBusOptions.java:41)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.createHandlers(NodeServer.java:117)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.asServer(NodeServer.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.node.httpd.NodeServer.execute(NodeServer.java:231)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.TemplateGridCommand.lambda$configure$4(TemplateGridCommand.java:129)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.launch(Main.java:83)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.go(Main.java:57)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Main.main(Main.java:42)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Bootstrap.runMain(Bootstrap.java:77)
        at org.openqa.selenium.grid.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:70)
12:03:53.760 WARN [UnboundZmqEventBus.lambda$new$3] - Connecting to tcp://selenium-hub:4442 and tcp://selenium-hub:4443 failed
12:04:03.520 WARN [UnboundZmqEventBus.lambda$new$4] - Failure #1. Retrying.
```

Comment: The symptoms are vaguely consistent with the selenium nodes being restarted all the time. But there is not enough useful information supplied to determine this, or why.

Comment: @ChrisBecke I have added some additional information

Comment: What does `docker stack ps` say about the tasks and how long they have been running? If they are short lived, does `docker service logs <taskid>` for a stopped task then show why it stopped? Inspecting an actual dead container can tell you if it stopped because of out of memory or a healtcheck.

Comment: Memory is not getting full, probably a healthcheck, I have attached logs

Comment: "selenium-hub" is not resolving. Your stack is either messing up the network / service aliases, or 7946/* (swarm dns gossip) is blocked.